# How to deploy or install Cloudera CDH on Google's GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloudera-cdh

I am trying to install CDH on GCP using Cloudera Altus director but it fails in the last step to configure cluster and throws an error of "Bootstrap failed" with error  description as "Insufficient number of instances available after allocation".
I have followed all the steps mentioned in the following URL,but unable to deploy/install it.
https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/director/latest/topics/director_get_started_gcp.html
Tried to search for this error, but no solution found.
Can anybody help in this case?

Comment: This means that the cloudera director failed to the required number of instances required for the setup. What you have posted is a very generic error message. The exact sequence of errors can be best found in the apps log or syslog if you have this handy